# How to end peer connection in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webrtc, peerjs, react-native-webrtc

how can i end peer connection when using react-native-peerjs..The connection is successful& the call works. but at the point of ending the call, i haven't found a disconnect function, so the call still goes on in background till i restart the app.

my connection is like this

```
 const peerServer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: 'mvmarketserver.herokuapp.com',
    config: {
        iceServers: [
            {url:'stun:eu-turn3.xirsys.com'},
            {
                username: "",
                credential: "",
                credentialType: 'password',
                urls: [
                    "turn:eu-turn3.xirsys.com:80?transport=udp",
                    "turn:eu-turn3.xirsys.com:3478?transport=udp",
                    "turn:eu-turn3.xirsys.com:80?transport=tcp",
                    "turn:eu-turn3.xirsys.com:3478?transport=tcp",
                    "turns:eu-turn3.xirsys.com:443?transport=tcp",
                    "turns:eu-turn3.xirsys.com:5349?transport=tcp",
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    secure: true,
    port: 443,
    path: '/mypeer'
})

peerServer.on('error', console.log)
```

Currently my disconnect is like this, i try to use new Peer() to see if creating a new one, ends the previous one.Please help

```
dispatch({type: DELETE_STREAM, payload: []})
    dispatch({type: DELETE_MY_STREAM, payload: null})
    dispatch({type: DELETE_REMOTE_STREAM, payload: []})
KeepAwake.deactivate()
            SoundPlayer.stop()
            const roomID = this.state.room;
            console.log('leave ' + roomID);
            socket.emit('end-call', {roomID}); 
            const peer = new Peer();
            console.log('disconnected')
            InCallManager.stop({ busytone: '_DTMF_'})
            this.props.leaveRoom()
            const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
            goBack(null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I use native peerConnection but maybe you can try this way.

```
peerServer.on('connection', conn => {
    conn.on('close', () => {
        console.log("Close PeerConnection");
        conn.close();
    });
})
```

But if this does't work, maybe conn.on('close') not trigered.
https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/636

if you are using SocketIo you can add suck event as

```
socket.broadcast.emit("user-disconnected", {SOME_DATA_WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND});
```

and you can on event in client

```
socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId)=>{
    // Close peer connection or remove all video or audio stream
    closePeer()
});
```

create closePeer function

```
function closePeer() {
    for (let conns in peerServer.connections) {
      peerServer.connections[conns].forEach((conn, index, array) => {
        conn.peerConnection.close();
        if (conn.close)
          conn.close();
      });
    }
  }
```